# How to add data for sql to combobox?

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

this code is working

`TextBoxService is a combobox`

```vb
Connection()
Dim sql As String
CON.Open()
DTS = New DataSet
sql = "SELECT * FROM Service"
dap = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, CON)
dap.Fill(DTS, "Service")
TextBoxService.DataSource = DTS.Tables("Service")
TextBoxService.DisplayMember = "ServiceName"
TextBoxService.ValueMember = "ServiceID"
```

because I need to at it to 2 comboboxes. it will change both comboboxes when I selectd a combobox.
 so i try to use this

```vb
bds = New BindingSource
DTS = New DataSet
bds.DataSource = DTS.Tables("Service")
TextBoxService.DataSource = bds
TextBoxService.DisplayMember = "ServiceName"
TextBoxService.ValueMember = "ServiceID"
```

but it show this error `Cannot bind to the new display member`

Comment: Try to store DTS.Tables("Service") in two different datatables instead of use BindingSource. Then use one datatable for each combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to this the easy and simple I find is if you

*import the SQL data base in data sources
*Select the table you want and set the object type eg( combobox, textbox or checkbox)
*Then select eg combobox and click on the small arrow to the top left hand corner
*Select you data source(table), display member(field name)
* then go to the properties of the combobox object and select data binding plus sign
* click on text and click the data source (table) and field you want to display the data from

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as

Declare SQLConnection Declare SQLDataReader Declare SQLCommand

```vb
Try
    If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = Con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select field1, field2 from table"


    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
    Do While dr.Read = True
        ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
        ComboBoxName.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1))
    Loop

    Con.Close()
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)

End Try
```

Hope it works for you.